# svg text-centering anomaly

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I need to set SVG parameter text-anchor:"middle" for a set of single character tspan elements centered in small circles for a guitar chord chart generator: see http://chordography.blogspot.co.uk/.

When I paste the svg code into a browser: Chrome, IE, Firefox, Opera, Safari, or in Open Office Writer, the  characters are placed left of centre, EXCEPT for the last tspan element, which is centered correctly. The last one is always OK, even if I rearrange the tspans. The problem may not be noticeable in most cases, but sticks out like a sore thumb in this application.

Here, the plot thickens. When I insert the svg code directly into the DOM with JavaScript, as is normal in Chordography, all tspan elements centre correctly. And there is one more twist; when I paste the code in Blogger, it also centres properly, as shown at http://chordography.blogspot.co.uk/p/blog-page_58.html.

Here is the code for the relevant parts derived from XMLSerializer, showing the locations of the circles and inset 'labels'. Only the final '1' is properly centered, along with the final 'A' in the footer.

```
<g class="dots">
   <circle cx="62.1" cy="73.6" r="9.6"/>
   <circle cx="85.1" cy="128.8" r="9.6"/>
   <circle cx="108.1" cy="128.8" r="9.6"/>
   <circle cx="131.1" cy="128.8" r="9.6"/>
   <circle cx="154.1" cy="73.6" r="9.6"/>
</g>
<g text-anchor="middle" class="text">
   <text class="labels">
      <tspan x="62.1" y="79.2">1</tspan>
      <tspan x="85.1" y="134.4">2</tspan>
      <tspan x="108.1" y="134.4">3</tspan>
      <tspan x="131.1" y="134.4">4</tspan>
      <tspan x="154.1" y="79.2">1</tspan>
   </text>
   <text class="footer">
      <tspan x="39.1" y="189.6"> </tspan>
      <tspan x="62.1" y="189.6">D</tspan>
      <tspan x="85.1" y="189.6">A</tspan>
      <tspan x="108.1" y="189.6">D</tspan>
      <tspan x="131.1" y="189.6">F♯</tspan>
      <tspan x="154.1" y="189.6">A</tspan>
   </text>
</g>
```

All a bit bizarre; any ideas anyone.

Comment: What is the code you're pasting? Please include all relevant materials here whenever possible.

Comment: Jon, the svg code is generated by JS in the DOM, and serialized to a text-box, then copied/pasted into markup. But here is a sample:

  <g class="text" fill="green" style="text-anchor:middle;" >
    <text class="header">
      <tspan x="35.5" y="47">x</tspan>
      </text>
    <text class="labels">
      <tspan x="56.5" y="72">1</tspan>
      <tspan x="77.5" y="122">2</tspan>
      <tspan x="98.5" y="122">3</tspan>
      <tspan x="119.5" y="122">4</tspan>
      <tspan x="140.5" y="72">1</tspan>
      </text>

Comment: Just edit your answer to include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add 'text-anchor="middle"' to each tspan you will center them (you have to **remove the space between the 'tspans' as well**, otherwise the extra space will be considered as part of the first line and they won't be completely centered).

The space is most likely the reason you are having this issue.

The tspans look like this ...

```
<tspan text-anchor="middle" x="56.5" y="72">1</tspan><tspan
text-anchor="middle" x="77.5" y="122">2</tspan><tspan
text-anchor="middle" x="98.5" y="122">3</tspan><tspan
text-anchor="middle" x="119.5" y="122">4</tspan><tspan
text-anchor="middle" x="140.5" y="72">1</tspan>
```

Reference jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/0u5wmevm/

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED
You da man. Its the spaces AFTER the tspan that cause the problem. Newline and space before are OK. Thanks for the prompt responses.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I'd regex all unwanted characters, then read string as array, eg:

```
var badStr = 'xx,1p23,4 "5'; // string with errors
var newStr = str.replace(/[^x\d]/g,''); // outputs: x12345
console.log(newstr[1]); // debug, outputs: 1
```

Comment: Thanks Alvin, but I suspect I wasn't very clear. Its not bad characters in the data input strings that causes the problem, its the spaces in the code in a text element, in between tspan elements.

Comment: Yup, the first answer by @rfomal is correct. Big picture: This single `.replace()` solves the spacing problem (plus any errors too).